# How to clone all remote branches in Git lab?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-checkout

I have a master and a development branch, both pushed to Git lab. I've cloned, pulled, and fetched, but I remain unable to get anything other than the master branch back.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I have read the manual and I'm getting no joy at all.

Comment: Can you clarify the sequence of actions you're performing, and the exact error you get?

Comment: Olny the master branch is pushed by default. You need to add the dev branch manually to the origin. I don't remember the syntax off the top of my head, but it shouldn't be too hard to find

Comment: Thanks ! I also try to find ...http://stackoverflow.com/users/574621/merm

Answer (score 3):

You see your development branch in Gitlab?

What shows

```
git branch -a
```

?

You can "activate" your development branch with

```
git checkout development
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

When you clone you have all the information downloaded to your `.git` folder

To view all the branches use this:

```
git branch -a
```

To checkout locally all your branches use this

```
# loop over all the branches check them all out
for branch in `git branch -r | grep remotes | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master `; do
git checkout $branch
```

done

#### What does the script do?

**`git branch -r`**
get a list of all the remote branches

**`| grep remotes`**
The branch names are : 'remotes/origin/' so this will remove the remotes from the branch names

**`| grep -v HEAD`**
Filter HEAD from the branches list

**`| grep -v master`**
Filter `master`` from the branches list since you already have it locally

Answer (score 0):

Ansver like above, but for me do not work via "grep remotes"(I attached screen).. So:
git clone YOUR-URL;
cd to folder or press TAB :)
for branch in `git branch -r |grep "origin" |grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; do local_branch=$(echo "$branch" | sed '/^.*//!d; s///;q'); git checkout $branch; git branch $local_branch ; done;
git branch

Some description:
sed '/^.*//!d; s///;q'
to do from "origin/PROD_SERVICES"
this "PROD_SERVICES"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5sDb.png)